# hasActiveObservers and hasObservers false in shared ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm trying to communicate between two fragments and the ViewPager2 using shared ViewModel as follows:

SharedViewModel

```
val viewPagerFragment = MutableLiveData<Int>()

init {
    viewPagerFragment.value = -1
}

fun displayedFragment(fragmentIndex: Int){
    viewPagerFragment.value = fragmentIndex
}

fun doSomethingForFragmentA(){
    //
}

fun doSomethingForFragmentB(){
    //
}
```

Fragment A

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    sharedViewModel.displayedFragment(0)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    sharedViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
}
```

Fragment B

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    sharedViewModel.displayedFragment(1)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    sharedViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
}
```

ViewPager2

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    sharedViewModel.viewPagerFragment.observe(this, Observer {
        when (it) {
            0 -> sharedViewModel.doSomethingForFragmentA(it)
            1 -> sharedViewModel.doSomethingForFragmentB(it)
        }
    })

}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    sharedViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
}
```

During the first call of the onActivityCreated in the ViewPager2, the LiveData Observer reacts correctly. However, both hasActiveObservers and hasObservers show false in the shared ViewModel.
When I toggle from FragmentA to FragmentB, the FragmentB updates the LiveData correctly in onResume(). This time Observer in the ViewPager2 does not react to the change and the hasActiveObservers and hasObservers are still false.

It is worth mentioning that if I move observers from ViewPager to FragmentA and FragmentB everything works fine.

The only thing that comes to mind is that the ViewPager has a different host activity.

Comment: Can you post the part where you assign `activityViewModel` and `sharedViewModel`?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been sharedViewModel. All three references are initialized in onCreate in each fragment (Fragment A, Fragment B and ViewPager2). The ViewPager2 is essentially a third fragment. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: can you try using `ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity())` instead of `ViewModelProvider(this)` as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) and see how it goes

Comment: ViewModelProviders is deprecated in lifecycle 2.2.0. It is retrieved by a delegate: by viewModels(), but I've already tried this and it didn't work either.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. So `getActivity()` still didn't work? I think the viewmodel cannot be shared if you pass in `this`, which is a fragment. The viewmodel should be bound to activity to be shared no?

Comment: If ViewPager and FragmentA, FragmentB are hosted in different activity then it will not work even if you pass in activity context.. How about putting the livedata in a singleton or a singleton-like object?

Comment: That was my initial thought, but FragmentA and FragmentB don't have a problem with observing the LiveData object. I pass "this" as the lifecycle owner in both fragments. I also used Koin to inject the same ViewModel object in all three fragments. I defined a module

val viewmodelModule = module {
    viewModel { SharedViewModel() }
}

and then I injected in all three fragments

val sharedViewModel by inject<SharedViewModel>()

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue using Channels. Not exactly what I wanted, but it works. I still hope there is a solution to the original question.

AppContainer

```
class AppContainer {
    val currentViewPagerFragmentChannel = Channel<Int>()
}
```

BaseApplication

```
class BaseApplication : Application(){

    val appContainer = AppContainer()
}
```

FragmentA

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val app = activity?.application as BaseApplication


    GlobalScope.launch {
        app.appContainer.currentViewPagerFragmentChannel.send(0)
    }
}
```

FragmentB

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val app = activity?.application as BaseApplication

    // Send an Integer
    GlobalScope.launch {
        app.appContainer.currentViewPagerFragmentChannel.send(1)
    }
}
```

ViewPager

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    launch {
        val app = activity?.application as BaseApplication
        val ch = app.appContainer.currentViewPagerFragmentChannel

        if (!ch.isClosedForSend){
            for (value in ch){
                when (value) {
                    // FragmentA is displayed
                    0 -> sharedViewModel.doSomethingForFragmentA(value)
                    // FragmentB is displayed
                    1 -> sharedViewModel.doSomethingForFragmentB(value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```